# How to optimize server for use of many regular expressions operations

Tags: php, apache

My server is running slow due to high CPU usage. I've tracked down the source of the high CPU usage to a couple of causes:

- a large number of regexp funcions on datasets.
- strpos, substr operations.
- Loops through arrays for basic mathematical operations.

All these operations are required for one search on my website. If a visitor does a search the CPU goes to 100%. There is nothing I can do about these operations because they are required.

My questions:

- What would be the best way to configure configuration files such as httpd.conf or php.ini given that the operations above are the cause for almost all CPU usage?
- What would be the best way to upgrade the server given that the operations above are the cause for almost all CPU usage?

UPDATE 1:

An example of an operation is:

```
preg_match_all('/ValuesBreakdown_\d+_[A-Z]+_out.push\(([\d.,]+)/',$content,$matches);
```

This single operation does not use a lot of CPU, but it is the large number of this kind of operation that adds up.

Comment: Can you elaborate on a situation where all of those are _REQUIRED_ to be like that?

Comment: you could maybe reduce the load by using an opcode cache that holds the php files and caching for the results, too.

Comment: All those operations are required for a single search on my website. I scrape a lot of data from a large number of websites at once, and all the data has to be parsed an checked.

Comment: Are you using a database, or are you searching through flat files? Not sure why a search should require so much.

Comment: I'm not sure if caching would help because each time the data is different.

Comment: I use a database too but all queries are quick and don't use a much CPU. It are flat files (content from websites)

Comment: Why can't you take snapshots of your data, then index and use that for searching? Only be server resource intensive every hour or two, then clients can search "fairly recent" data instead of "UP TO THE SECOND"

Comment: It won't work because if I would index everything it would be a MASSIVE amount of data.

Comment: Add more information on the operations that are taking so much time. Determine what is causing the CPU load - isolate the regular expression causing the pronlem.

Comment: are the things you are searching your own website's or external websites?

Comment: I know what is causing the CPU load: operations that are necessary so I would like to know how to best deal with those operations.

Comment: I crab content from external websites. Around 60 websites per search.

Comment: @BastiaanWesteinde well most search site's like Google crawl webpage's and then put content into their own databases to be indexed for fast search. any other method is simply not performant. if you could find a way to make this performant without that, you would be a millionaire.

Comment: @dqhendricks if the search contains only 30 websites, the CPU is not overloaded and the search finishes within 20 seconds. Which is acceptable for my application. If I would use 2 machines for 60 websites It should be possible as well. I think therefore it should be possible to optimize only I'd prefer to use only one server. The number of websites that google searches is - of course - un-comparable with my situation.

Comment: @BastiaanWesteinde if it is only 30 sites, then you should be able to cache them all in a database fairly easily.

Comment: @dqhendricks The content on those websites is dynamic so every time I grab content from those 30 websites it returns different content.

Comment: Find some individual regexps and mathematical operations that you can verify as contributors to the problem (run them on their own and see if they produce a non-negligible fraction of the CPU load you're getting). Then post them here (in obfuscated form, if you need to). Some of these folks can probably help optimize specific processes, but I don't think there's any generic way to make things better based on the information you've given so far.

Comment: @BastiaanWesteinde You could have a cronjob that caches them each night or something along those lines.

Comment: @dqhendricks One website can on average return 1E9 different results, I don't think caching will work. In addition all that data changes on hourly basis.

Comment: @BastiaanWesteinde instead of using regex etc to search their site data with your code, can't you use that site's search mechanism to do the search for you?

Comment: @dqhendricks I scrape the data after posting a form, that data is generated by their search mechanism, then I need to parse out the information I need from the raw content. This is the only way as they don't have a api yet.

Comment: You can try traversing the DOM tree to find data instead of using regex in some places to see what performs better.

Answer (score 0):

When facing performance issues, always make sure that the cause is really what you think it is.

My advise is first to use XDebug + webgrind for instance and confirm the cause(s).

Then you will probably be able to change the logic-flow of your code in order to improve perfs : for instance are you looping several times your dataset instead of only one time? Are you sure you cannot improve your algorithm? etc..

At every time use XDebug to prove to yourself that you actually improved perf.